# Android App and PHP Web Service Security

Tags: java, php, android, web-services

I'm building an android application which uses a PHP web service (I am building this also).

My question is, how do I prevent unauthorised users using my webservice? For example, could someone get the address of my web service and use it outside of my app (e.g. sending post variables to my service)?

Another related question is how do I prevent spam requests on my webservice? Would it be a case of logging the IP address and limiting the amount of calls?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `HTTPS` connection between the Android device and your webservice API endpoint.

Limit you webservice so that it accept only `HTTPS` connections. You can easily do this using Apache (perhaps using the [SSLRequireSSL directive](http://www.apache-ssl.org/docs.html#SSLRequireSSL)) or directly in your PHP connection handler.

While using an `HTTPS` transport stream, you can pass specific arguments when making an API call to your webservice to ensure the request has been sent from your application. Nobody will be able to know what specific data are transmitted and will not be able to reproduce an *acceptable* connection to your remote service.

Regarding your second question, you can indeed limit the number of requests for a given amount of time. Either in PHP or by using specific tools such as [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

Answer (score 0):

PHP can receive data via POST or GET out of your site and even the internet browser. One of the methods used to do this is by [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/).

To what are you referring to this question is known as [Cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

If you are able, you should implement the use of [HTTPS](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/) in your app and this could solve many security problems.

**In case you can not use HTTPS** (whether it is expensive or any other problem):

You must verify the information received by POST or GET in your PHP, this language has much ability to solve these "problems"; Take a look at this [part](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) of the PHP official [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/).

Suppose you're building a login system:
Also you can add in the login page place a hidden element with secret unique code that can happend only once, save this secret code in session, so, the loging script look in session for this code, compare with what was posted to the script, should same to proceed.

And, if you want to get the IP address of your visitors:

```
function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Finally, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242210/allow-get-request-but-only-in-my-domain).

**EDIT**

If you can't pay an HTTPS certificate, (as [Halim Qarroum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175633/halim-qarroum) says) you can use:

> [Self signed SSL certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate),
>   which are free.
>   Of course this has its advantages and disadvantages

Comment: If he does not use a secured `HTTPS` connection, passing data in clear could be potentially read by any body by the mean of different types of attacks. If an attacker can read what data are sent to his API, he could reproduce the intercepted request to make the webservice think he is the actual Android application.

Comment: He did not ask how to prevent that attack, simply remarked that using HTTPS can solve many security problems like that you just mentioned.
If he can not pay a https connection, he can do what I mentioned, if he can pay, then that will solve many problems.

Comment: HTTPS is not a question of cost. Third party signed certificates can be expensive but nothing prevents you from using self signed certificates in this case. Also, he did ask how to prevent unauthorized access to his service : `My question is, how do I prevent unauthorised users using my webservice?`.

Comment: I took that question like "how I can prevent that unauthorized users affect my system sending data via POST or GET?"

Having HTTPS can be expensive in many countries, like where I live, Argentina.
Maybe he does not have money to pay, but just want to make your APP as safe as possible, then, if he can pay and implement it, great, otherwise, if he can not pay, then I suggested to read these official documentation and links to make her system a bit more robust.

Comment: As I said, he also can use self signed SSL certificates : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate. Which are free. Of course this has its advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: I cited your suggestion in my answer.